# Getting the dictionary from model query

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to get the dictionary while query on Django Model instead of list of objects??
For example:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
objs = someModel.objects.filter(pk__in = ids)
```

It returns me list of objects. What i want is somehow if i can, i want dictionary of objects with primary key as key.

```
objs = {1: query_object, 2: quer_object, 3: quer_object, 4: quer_object, 5: quer_object}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension ( http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-dict_comprehension - available in python 2.7.2 and possibly earlier):

```
{ obj.pk:obj for obj in objs }
```

Apart from being more explicit and compact, this avoids the creation of an intermediate list or generator object.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to put ValuesListQuerySet object in to "in_bulk" method like this:

```
someModel_query = someModel.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
someModel.objects.in_bulk(someModel_query)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension to create that manually:

```
dict([(obj.pk, obj) for obj in objs])
```